# Get previous element in IObservable without re-evaluating the sequence

Tags: c#, system.reactive

In an `IObservable` sequence (in Reactive Extensions for .NET), I'd like to get the value of the previous and current elements so that I can compare them.  I found an example online similar to below which accomplishes the task:

```
sequence.Zip(sequence.Skip(1), (prev, cur) => new { Previous = prev, Current = cur })
```

It works fine except that it evaluates the sequence twice, which I would like to avoid.  You can see that it is being evaluated twice with this code:

```
var debugSequence = sequence.Do(item => Debug.WriteLine("Retrieved an element from sequence"));
debugSequence.Zip(debugSequence.Skip(1), (prev, cur) => new { Previous = prev, Current = cur }).Subscribe();
```

The output shows twice as many of the debug lines as there are elements in the sequence.

I understand why this happens, but so far I haven't found an alternative that doesn't evaluate the sequence twice.  How can I combine the previous and current with only one sequence evaluation?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There's a better solution to this I think, that uses Observable.Scan and avoids the double subscription:

```
public static IObservable<Tuple<TSource, TSource>>
    PairWithPrevious<TSource>(this IObservable<TSource> source)
{
    return source.Scan(
        Tuple.Create(default(TSource), default(TSource)),
        (acc, current) => Tuple.Create(acc.Item2, current));
}
```

I've written this up on my blog here: http://www.zerobugbuild.com/?p=213

#### Addendum

A further modification allows you to work with arbitrary types more cleanly by using a result selector:

```
public static IObservable<TResult> CombineWithPrevious<TSource,TResult>(
    this IObservable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TSource, TResult> resultSelector)
{
    return source.Scan(
        Tuple.Create(default(TSource), default(TSource)),
        (previous, current) => Tuple.Create(previous.Item2, current))
        .Select(t => resultSelector(t.Item1, t.Item2));
}
```

Comment: Link to blog provides a use case for the first not the second solution. Here's one: `myObservable.CombineWithPrevious((older, newer) => (older > 0) && (newer == 0))` will detect when some value just got down to zero. Could be filtered further with `.Where(v => v == true);`

Answer (score 5):

@James World addendum looks great to me, if not for `Tuple<>`, which I almost always dislike: "*Was .Item1 the previous? Or was it the current one? I can't remember. And what's the first argument to the selector, was it the previous item?*".

For that part I liked @dcstraw definition of a dedicated `ItemWithPrevious<T>`. So there you go, putting the two together (hopefully I did not mix up previous with current) with some renaming and facilities:

```cs
public static class ObservableExtensions
{
    public static IObservable<SortedPair<TSource>> CombineWithPrevious<TSource>(
        this IObservable<TSource> source, 
        TSource initialValue = default(TSource))
    {
        var seed = SortedPair.Create(initialValue, initialValue);

        return source.Scan(seed,
            (acc, current) => SortedPair.Create(current, acc.Current));
    }

    public static IObservable<TResult> CombineWithPrevious<TSource, TResult>(
        this IObservable<TSource> source,
        Func<SortedPair<TSource>, TResult> resultSelector,
        TSource initialValue = default(TSource))
    {
        var seed = SortedPair.Create(initialValue, initialValue);

        return source
            .Scan(seed,
                (acc, current) => SortedPair.Create(current, acc.Current))
            .Select(p => resultSelector(p));
    }
}

public class SortedPair<T>
{
    public SortedPair(T current, T previous)
    {
        Current = current;
        Previous = previous;
    }

    public SortedPair(T current) : this(current, default(T)) { }

    public SortedPair() : this(default(T), default(T)) { }

    public T Current;
    public T Previous;
}

public class SortedPair
{
    public static SortedPair<T> Create<T>(T current, T previous)
    {
        return new SortedPair<T>(current, previous);
    }

    public static SortedPair<T> Create<T>(T current)
    {
        return new SortedPair<T>(current);
    }

    public static SortedPair<T> Create<T>()
    {
        return new SortedPair<T>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Evaluating twice is an indicator of a **Cold observable**. You can turn it to a Hot one by using .Publish():

```
var pub = sequence.Publish();
pub.Zip(pub.Skip(1), (...
pub.Connect();
```

Comment: Found an easy to digest article about the difference between Hot and Cold Observables: http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/bnaya/archive/2010/03/13/rx-for-beginners-part-9-hot-vs-cold-observable.aspx

Comment: Using Publish and Connect I still see the side effects of the Zip(Skip(1), ...) occur twice.  I suppose it's not really the original source I needed to evaluate once, but the IObservable query itself.  Still, thanks for the info.

Comment: @dcstraw Strange, I published the debugSequence from your example above (I used Observable.Range for the sequence) and it evaluated once for me. Using .Publish in the described situation is pretty much a no-brainer in the RX land...

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to access the previous element during subscription, this is probably the simplest thing that will work.  (I'm sure there's a better way, maybe a buffer operator on IObservable?  The documentation is pretty sparse at the moment, so I can't really tell you.)

```
    EventArgs prev = null;

    sequence.Subscribe(curr => 
    {
        if (prev != null)
        {
            // Previous and current element available here
        }

        prev = curr;                              

    });
```

EventArgs is just a stand-in for the type of your event's argument.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I do however need the previous element before subscription because I would like to filter the sequence based on logic using the previous and current.

Comment: Got it; i'll do a bit more research

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is great, the only change I propose is to use [Tuple field names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples#tuple-field-names) instead of Tuple.Create or a result selector.

```
public static IObservable<(T? Previous, T? Current)> CombineWithPrevious<T>(this IObservable<T> source)
{
  (T? Previous, T? Current) seed = (default(T), default(T));
  return source.Scan(seed, (combination, latest) => (combination.Current, latest));
}
```

Example usage:

```
var foo = bar.CombineWithPrevious().Select(x => $"{x.Current} {x.Previous}");
```

Answer (score -1):

It turns out you can use a variable to hold the previous value and refer to it and reassign it within the chain of `IObservable` extensions.  This even works within a helper method.  With the code below I can now call `CombineWithPrevious()` on my `IObservable` to get a reference to the previous value, without re-evaluating the sequence.

```
public class ItemWithPrevious<T>
{
    public T Previous;
    public T Current;
}

public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IObservable<ItemWithPrevious<T>> CombineWithPrevious<T>(this IObservable<T> source)
    {
        var previous = default(T);

        return source
            .Select(t => new ItemWithPrevious<T> { Previous = previous, Current = t })
            .Do(items => previous = items.Current);
    }
}
```

Comment: This has (an unfortunately common) bug! Avoid using "Do" because it introduces a side-effect; it's executed for every subscriber. This code breaks for every subscription to a given CombineWithPrevious invocation after the first because the second and subsequent subscriptions will cause Do to overwrite the previous value with the current one. So this works: `source.CombineWithPrevious().Subscribe(first); source.CombineWithPrevious().Subscribe(second);` but this doesn't: `var x = source.CombineWithPrevious(); x.Subscribe(first); x.Subscribe(second);` See my answer below for a correct approach.