# Rx programming, how to combine item with former element in single observable?

Tags: reactive-programming, rx-scala

If we have the observable:

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> ...
```

how to construct to the new observable:

```
(1, 2) -> (3, 4) -> ...
```

Maybe the question to short but I really not find how to achieve.Thank you

Thanks every one ,I find a method and under consider remove var

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

import rx.lang.scala.{Subject, Observable}

import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
object ObservableEx {
   implicit class ObservableImpl[T](src: Observable[T]) {
     /**
       * 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 ->...
       * (1,2) -> (3,4) -> ...
       */
     def pair: Observable[(T, T)] = {
       val sub = Subject[(T, T)]()
       var former: Option[T] = None //help me to kill it
       src.subscribe(
         x => {
           if (former.isEmpty) {
             former = Some(x)
           }
           else {
             sub.onNext(former.get, x)
             former = None
           }
         },
         e => sub.onError(e),
         () => sub.onCompleted()
       )

       sub
     }
   }
}

object Test extends App {
  import ObservableEx._
  val pair = Observable.interval(Duration(1L, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).pair
  pair.subscribe(x => println("1 - " + x))
  pair.subscribe(x => println("2 - " + x))

  Thread.currentThread().join()
}
```

I didn't like var at all, thanks again!

**FINALLY**
I get a light way, hope can help others.

```
 def pairPure[T](src: Observable[T]): Observable[(T, T)] = {
   def pendingPair(former: Option[T], sub: Subject[(T, T)]): Unit = {
     val p = Promise[Unit]
     val subscription = src.subscribe(
       x => {
         if (former.isEmpty) {
           p.trySuccess(Unit)
           pendingPair(Some(x), sub)
         }
         else {
           sub.onNext(former.get, x)
           p.trySuccess(Unit)
           pendingPair(None, sub)
         }
       },
       e => sub.onError(e),
       () => sub.onCompleted()
     )

     p.future.map{x => subscription.unsubscribe()}
   }

   val sub = Subject[(T,T)]()
   pendingPair(None, sub)
   sub
 }
```

Other answers also very helpful~

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get previous element in IObservable without re-evaluating the sequence](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820685/get-previous-element-in-iobservable-without-re-evaluating-the-sequence)

Comment: @KeithHall, I have find another similar way by construct a new observable.`Scan` is a good idea but I also want complete my idea.If you has some advice,thank a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [tumblingBuffer](http://reactivex.io/rxscala/scaladoc/index.html#rx.lang.scala.Observable@tumblingBuffer%28count:Int%29:rx.lang.scala.Observable[Seq[T]]) with `count = 2` to get an `Observable` of `Seq`s of length 2, and using `map`, you can turn them into pairs:

```scala
implicit class ObservableImpl[T](src: Observable[T]) {
  def pair: Observable[(T, T)] = {
    def seqToPair(seq: Seq[T]): (T, T) = seq match {
      case Seq(first, second) => (first, second)
    } 
    src.tumblingBuffer(2).map(seqToPair)
  }
}
```

Note that this will fail if the number of elements in the source Observable is odd, so you will have to cover this case in `seqToPair`.

Comment: I also get a light way.Yours is also great.

Answer (score 0):

Try [groupBy](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/groupby.html) operator.
Good luck.

Comment: hi, my friend, can't make Observable[T] to Observable[(T, T)]?